# Azure devops REST API comment field contains extra HTML tags

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Azure devops REST api to fetch the comments for respective work items. I am getting extra HTML tags in the text fields apart from actual comments(see fig).
Because of these extra tags I am not able import comments. Looking for help

[image]
REST API URL: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get-comments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjAGI.png)

Comment: this link may help you-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get-comments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: I am already using this document for api info and also tagged in my question.
do you have something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a python script to remove HTML tags from text. Every time i make an API calls and get the comments and parse through this function to remove redundant HTML tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def remove_html_tag(text) -> Any:
"""
Function to remove html tag from text .

Args:
    text: Text containing html tag.
Returns:
    Any
"""

cleantext = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml").text
return (cleantext)

text= "<span style=\"box-sizing:border-box;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);display:inline !important;\">test comment 06/08 repeat in new tab</span><br>"
answer = remove_html_tag(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this doc: [Import or update rich-text fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#import-or-update-rich-text-fields)

> The description and acceptance criteria field are rich-text fields. Rich-text fields are HTML formatted fields.

The discussion field is similar to the description field(multi-line text boxes). So it is rich-text fields. When you use Rest API to export the comments, it will contain the HTML tag.

As far as I know, the html format is  used to keep formatting elements in the exported/import content.

When you import the commnet, you need to add the html tag. After import, these html will be converted into normal format.

For example:

[image]

Result:

[image]